# Outlook access shared inbox sub-folder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a strange issue on the below code I use for extracting Outlook email information into Excel. Sometimes the code works perfectly but other times I get the **Run-Time Error** **`'-2147221233 (8004010f)'`**. When I do get this error it is the line **`Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox").Folders("ARCHIVE")`** that has the issue.

I am running the code on a shared inbox and I have the "ARCHIVE" folder as a sub-folder of the inbox. It is as if the code cannot find the folder even though it is there and it can find it sometimes.

My uneducated guess is that, since a shared inbox can have a delay updating across all users, if there is any action in the folder the code cannot recognize the folder until it refreshes or updates on the server.

Can anybody suggest slightly different code so that it will run every time? Or does anybody have an explanation as to why it only occasionally works as is?

```
Sub EmailStatsV3()
'Working macro for exporting specific sub-folders of a shared inbox
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim aOutput() As Variant
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlSh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim flInbox As Folder

'Gets the mailbox and shared folder inbox
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Operations") 

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objInbox = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)

'Uses the Parent of the Inbox to specify the mailbox
strFolderName = objInbox.Parent

'Specifies the folder (inbox or other) to pull the info from
Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders(strFolderName)
Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox").Folders("ARCHIVE") 'Change this line to specify folder
Set colItems = objFolder.Items

'Specify which email items to extract
ReDim aOutput(1 To objFolder.Items.Count, 1 To 10)
For Each olMail In objFolder.Items
If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" Then

        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        aOutput(lCnt, 1) = olMail.SenderEmailAddress 'Sender or SenderName also gives similar output
        aOutput(lCnt, 2) = olMail.ReceivedTime 'stats on when received
        aOutput(lCnt, 3) = olMail.ConversationTopic 'group based on subject w/o regard to prefix
        aOutput(lCnt, 4) = olMail.Subject 'to split out prefix
        aOutput(lCnt, 5) = olMail.Categories 'to split out category
        aOutput(lCnt, 6) = olMail.Sender
        aOutput(lCnt, 7) = olMail.SenderName
        aOutput(lCnt, 8) = olMail.To
        aOutput(lCnt, 9) = olMail.CC
        aOutput(lCnt, 10) = objFolder.Name
End If

Next

'Creates a blank workbook in excel then inputs the info from Outlook
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlSh = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)

xlSh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput
xlApp.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are running the code from Outlook, see the cleanup I did.

```
Option Explicit
Sub EmailStatsV3()
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim varOutput() As Variant
    Dim lngcount As Long
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ShareInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim SubFolder As Object

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@Email.com") '// Owner's Name or email address
    Set ShareInbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = ShareInbox.Folders("Temp") 'Change this line to specify folder

    ReDim varOutput(1 To SubFolder.Items.Count, 1 To 10)

    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
            lngcount = lngcount + 1
            varOutput(lngcount, 1) = Item.SenderEmailAddress 'Sender or SenderName
            varOutput(lngcount, 2) = Item.ReceivedTime 'stats on when received
            varOutput(lngcount, 3) = Item.ConversationTopic 'Conversation subject
            varOutput(lngcount, 4) = Item.Subject 'to split out prefix
            varOutput(lngcount, 5) = Item.Categories 'to split out category
            varOutput(lngcount, 6) = Item.Sender
            varOutput(lngcount, 7) = Item.SenderName
            varOutput(lngcount, 8) = Item.To
            varOutput(lngcount, 9) = Item.CC
            varOutput(lngcount, 10) = SubFolder.Name
        End If
    Next

    'Creates a blank workbook in excel
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlSht = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)

    xlSht.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(varOutput, 1), _
                             UBound(varOutput, 2)).Value = varOutput
    xlApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup. Yes I am running the code from Outlook. I tried running the macro with your changes and it worked for 2 sub-folders but then stopped working again when I tried to run it on a 3rd.I don't see what could be causing this to only occasionally work

Comment: @ColinTorpey  are getting the same error or different error?

Comment: Same error. I tried running again a few hours later and it worked but this is the problem I have. The code looks perfect but only occasionally works. I reckon it's a problem with the setup of the server or Outlook folders but that is only a guess. This is not a major issue for me but more of an annoyance.

Comment: Also would you know if it is possible to put a date filter into the code? For example if the email was received before a particular date then the code would stop or the mail would be ignored? Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: @ColinTorpey I'm not getting any Error, Try change `Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder` to `Dim SubFolder As Object`