# Outlook VBA how to setup listener in group folders

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to setup a listener in the group folder of my outlook. The way it should work is that whenever I get an email there a message box pops out. By 'group folder' I mean the folder as seen below:

[image]

I have successfully managed to perform the task with the default inbox folder using the code below, however I am really struggling to find a way to do it for the group folder:

```
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

' Setup listener to Inbox
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  
  Dim ShareInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim outlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient

  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
'  Set outlookRecip = objectNS.CreateRecipient("group_email@organisation.com")
'  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(outlookRecip, olFolderInbox)
  
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    
    MsgBox ("Hi")

End Sub
```

The closest that I have gotten is by following the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523609/outlook-access-shared-inbox-sub-folder#_=_) which I have implemented on the two commented lines on my code above. However when I uncomment these two lines and run the code I get the following error:

**The server mailbox cannot be opened because this address book entry is not a mail user**

Comment: Wondering if you could do this with an Outlook rule.  "Apply this rule after the message arrives through the _specified_ account and on this computer only display _after the message arrives_ in the New Item Alert window".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) value for the `GetDefaultFolder` method.

It it doesn't work then you need to iterate over Folders tree to get the right folders. For example, you may find the [Enumerate folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-enumerate-folders) article helpful. If they are located in the same store in Outlook. If not, you may iterate over the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) collection that represents all the Store objects in the current profile.

Comment: Tried your last suggestion successfully, unfortunately the Group folders do not appear there. If i search for 'Inbox' I get all of my subfolders, if I search for 'Groups' it says that they are not found...

Comment: How many stores do you have in the profile? Did you try to iterate over the `Stores` collection?

Answer (score 0):

Group calendars are not exposed for the programmatic access. On the low level, all group calendars are stored in a separate OST file.