# How to access Shared Mailbox using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to access a shared mailbox which I cannot add to my account as the admin won't allow it.
When I'm debugging my code, "set sharedmailbox" is showing the mail ID but the next step i.e inboxItems is showing "Nothing".

```
Option Explicit
Const xlUp As Long = -4162 'Set the enumeration for Excel's xlup
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim sharedmailbox As Outlook.Recipient

Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sharedmailbox = objectNS.CreateRecipient("shared@email.com").Folders("subfolder").Items
Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderInbox)

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to bypass the security settings the admin set up?

Comment: @braX I'm asking if the approach is correct for accessing the mailbox? I don't want to bypass the  security settings by the admin.

Comment: Delete `.Folders("subfolder").Items`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37537504/4539709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a *recipient* instance (which represents a shared user's mailbox) and then pass it to the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder).

```
Option Explicit
Const xlUp As Long = -4162 'Set the enumeration for Excel's xlup
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim sharedmailbox As Outlook.Recipient

  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set sharedmailbox = objectNS.CreateRecipient("shared@email.com")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderInbox)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes total sense!

Answer (score 0):

You declared `inboxItems` As `Outlook.Items`, but `GetSharedDefaultFolder` returns `MAPIFolder` object.
And `Recipient` object does not implement `Folders` property.

Change the lines

```
Set sharedmailbox = objectNS.CreateRecipient("shared@email.com").Folders("subfolder").Items
Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderInbox)
```

to (note `.Items` at the end of `GetSharedDefaultFolder` and no `.Folders` at the end of `CreateRecipient`):

```
Set sharedmailbox = objectNS.CreateRecipient("shared@email.com")
Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderInbox).Folders("subfolder").Items
```

Comment: Yea, I missed another problem that you had - `Recipient` does not implement `Folders` property. See the updated answer above.